# Datastore query outputting for Django form instance

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, forms, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using google appengine and Django. I'm using de djangoforms module and wanted to specify the form instance with the information that comes from the query below.

```
    userquery = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE googleaccount = :1", users.get_current_user())

    form = forms.AccountForm(data=request.POST or None,instance=?????)
```

I've found a snippet in a sample app that does this trick, but I can't modify it to work with the query I need.

```
    gift = User.get(db.Key.from_path(User.kind(), int(gift_id)))
    if gift is None:
         return http.HttpResponseNotFound('No gift exists with that key (%r)' %
                                   gift_id)
    form = RegisterForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=gift)
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the `userquery` will only have one `User` object in it (or if you only care about the first one if there are duplicates), you can modify your code like so:

```
userquery = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE googleaccount = :1", users.get_current_user())
user = userquery.get() # Gets the first User instance from the query, or None
form = forms.AccountForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=user)
```